# Display div for 2 seconds after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is possible to show a div for only 2 seconds when users come to my website?

```
<div class="message">
   <p>Hello, everybody this websites will be moved in 2 weeks</p>
</div>
```

maybe using jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to hide the div after 2 seconds on document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".message").hide(); }, 2000);
});
```

You can use [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) to animate the disappearance of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, which will hide the div after 2 seconds

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.message').fadeOut('fast');
}, 2000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use "hide", the element would not be visible, but the space it ocupies will still be there. Changing the attribute to "display: none", you will hide it while the empty space will disappear.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".message").attr("display", "none"); }, 2000);
});
```